# Center Google Maps position changed while keeping bottom padding

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

The center position is on top of the `mapView`. Is there any way for it to be centered? This is the code I'm currently using, but without luck:

```
 let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 150.0, right: 0.0)
 mapView.padding = mapInsets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set equal padding on both top and bottom or left and right center position will be updated.

```
let mapInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 150.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 150.0, right: 0.0)
mapView.padding = mapInsets
```